# Convert string with hard coded line breaks into matrix in python

Tags: python, oop, methods, python-class

I am trying to create a class that takes a string of digits with hard coded line breaks and outputs a matrix and details about that matrix. In the first instance i just want to be able to create the matrix but I am struggling. I'm aware that I could probably do this very easily with numpy or something similar but trying to practice.

```
class Matrix:
def __init__(self, matrix_string):
    self.convert_to_list = [int(s) for s in str.split(matrix_string) if s.isdigit()]
    self.split = matrix_string.splitlines()
```

I think i want to combine the two things I have already done but I cant figure out how to apply my convert_to_list method to every element in my split method.

Getting very confused.

SAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT

```
Input = " 1 8 7 /n 6 18 2 /n 1 9 7 "

Desired Output = [[1, 8, 7], [6, 18, 2], [1, 9, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a list of lists. For that you can use nested list comprehension.

```
s = " 1 8 7 /n 6 18 2 /n 1 9 7 "
lst = [[int(x) for x in r.split()] for r in s.split('/n')]
print(lst)
```

Output

```
[[1, 8, 7], [6, 18, 2], [1, 9, 7]]
```

Comment: That's great, thank you, yes i was struggling with the logic of that extra for loop. Really helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard actually:

```
s = " 1 8 7 /n 6 18 2 /n 1 9 7 "
print([i.split() for i in s.split('/n')])
```

easier way but longer:

```
s = s.split('/n')
new = []
for i in s:
    new.append(i.split())
print(new)
```

output:

```
[['1', '8', '7'], ['6', '18', '2'], ['1', '9', '7']]
```